# SQL - Distinct with Case When

Tags: sql

When i use the following query it returns duplicate External IDs as it lists the different cases as different rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT

    OENT.OTHER_EXTERNAL_ID                                                                                                      AS 'Agent Master Number'       
   ,CASE WHEN SE.Organization_Name IS NULL OR RTRIM(LTRIM(SE.ORGANIZATION_NAME)) = '' THEN '' ELSE SE.ORGANIZATION_NAME END     AS 'Agent'

   GROUP BY

    OENT.OTHER_EXTERNAL_ID                                                                                              
    ,CASE WHEN SE.Organization_Name IS NULL OR RTRIM(LTRIM(SE.ORGANIZATION_NAME)) = '' THEN '' ELSE SE.ORGANIZATION_NAME END
```

Where do i use the distinct properly so it lists the case as one row no matter what case it satisfies?

Thanks

Problem is that it keep returning

```
AGENT_NUMBER    AGENT

MA12348677  DREHWING, DOUGLAS

MA12348677  DREHWING, DOUGLAS A
```

Where i want this to be one row as they have the same AGENT_NUMBER

Comment: please add the correct dbms tag

Comment: if you want to count anything distinct is not your friend

Comment: Sorry count is the wrong word. I mean list.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (SQL Server, MySql, Postgresql)?

Comment: No table involved? (I see no FROM clause, perhaps just poor formatting...)

Comment: [edit] your question and add the definition of the tables (as `create table` statements) some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct
OENT.OTHER_EXTERNAL_ID AS AGENT_NUMBER,
CASE 
    WHEN SE.Organization_Name IS NULL OR RTRIM(LTRIM(SE.ORGANIZATION_NAME)) = '' THEN '' 
    ELSE upper( SE.ORGANIZATION_NAME )
END AS AGENT
FROM SomeTableName
order by AGENT_NUMBER
```

It will still return duplicates in case if Agent number differs. If you want to find duplicated names then

```
select AGENT, count (AGENT_NUMBER) from (
    select OENT.OTHER_EXTERNAL_ID AS AGENT_NUMBER,
    CASE 
        WHEN SE.Organization_Name IS NULL OR RTRIM(LTRIM(SE.ORGANIZATION_NAME)) = '' THEN '' 
        ELSE upper( SE.ORGANIZATION_NAME )
    END AS AGENT
    FROM SomeTableName
    )
    group by AGENT
    HAVING count (AGENT_NUMBER) >1
    order by AGENT
```

To find duplicate names for same Agent number:

```
select AGENT_NUMBER, count (AGENT) from (
    select OENT.OTHER_EXTERNAL_ID AS AGENT_NUMBER,
    CASE 
        WHEN SE.Organization_Name IS NULL OR RTRIM(LTRIM(SE.ORGANIZATION_NAME)) = '' THEN '' 
        ELSE upper( SE.ORGANIZATION_NAME )
    END AS AGENT
    FROM SomeTableName
    )
    group by AGENT_NUMBER
    HAVING count (AGENT) >1
    order by AGENT_NUMBER
```

Comment: A from clause isn't optional

Comment: Updated query. You can remove `HAVING count (AGENT) >1` if you want to see count for every agent.

Comment: Its showing an error for the first join after the FROM. When using a join where to i put the bracket?

Comment: Which database you have? Oracle? MSSQL? because that query is for Oracle. In case of MSSQL you'll have to change this line `FROM SomeTableName
    )
    group by AGENT_NUMBER` to this: `FROM SomeTableName
    ) as Main
    group by AGENT_NUMBER`